# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to determine the correct call signature - no procedure/function/signature for

Tags: linux, spring, jdbc, flyway, oracle12c

When i am trying to execute the function on Linux environment we are facing this issue. Rest of the environments(Like Windows & AIX) it is working fine.

Linux environment is using flyway script and the DB oracle 12C.

NOTE : Other environments are not using the Flyway scripts.
Please help.

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to determine the correct call signature - no procedure/function/signature for ''
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.GenericCallMetaDataProvider.processProcedureColumns(GenericCallMetaDataProvider.java:347) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.GenericCallMetaDataProvider.initializeWithProcedureColumnMetaData(GenericCallMetaDataProvider.java:112) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataProviderFactory$1.processMetaData(CallMetaDataProviderFactory.java:133) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:299) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataProviderFactory.createMetaDataProvider(CallMetaDataProviderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext.initializeMetaData(CallMetaDataContext.java:286) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.compileInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:303) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.compile(AbstractJdbcCall.java:288) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.checkCompiled(AbstractJdbcCall.java:348) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:386) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:193) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]

Comment: Please paste the full exception stack.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing something very similar for a procedure call that I'm using Spring's SimpleJdbcCall for too.  It started to appear when testing Oracle 12c.

Does adding withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess to the SimpleJdbcCall help?  So something like this:

```
new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName(procName).withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess().withCatalogName(pkgName);
```